# Can't boot to Linux after replacing Windows 7 with it while having another Windows 7 in another partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, windows-7

I'm new to Linux, I had 2 Windows 7 installed on my computer. So I wanted to install Linux instead of the other Windows so I changed the Windows partition to ext4 then without wiping it's data I installed Linux mint 20 cinnamon on it. However after I booted, it didn't show me any Linux booting ways and I still have 2 windows on my computer, but loading the other windows dispalys an error. Also I installed Linux using Unetbootin. And now, I can't access it back. It displays an error since I formatted my partition to ext4.
So I can't boot to linux test option.

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome.

Comment: Can it be helped at least?

Comment: Try https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Should I ask that there?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a problem with your bootloader. The installation of Linux mint probably went correctly, but its bootloader did not get installed. Can you in any way get to a grub rescue screen on your PC? Try booting directly to the disk you have installed linux on, with safe boot disabled. If you cannot find any other bootloaders then the windows one, try reinstalling grub! You can do this by booting from the usb again, and following this guide: https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/11/reinstall-grub-ubuntu-wont-boot/

Comment: I used unetbootin not usb

Comment: Uniboot is a tool that creates live USB-drives. To install linux, you need to create a live USB from a disc image with a tool like unetbootin, rufus or etcher. After that, you need to connect the usb to the computer and boot from it. You cannot install it directly to disc in that way. What I presume you did, was to burn the installation disk to your hard-drive. Try re-installing linux with a usb, since that is the proper way!